# SPRQL query , query about the hierarchy of instances in the ontology

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology

If I want to query about the hierarchy of my individual in the ontology (Protege). any idea how to write this query in SPRQL.

for example, person1 in individual in the ontology. how can I show in which class this person is belong?

Thanks

Comment: what did you try so far? I mean, that's one of the most fundamental SPARQL queries: `SELECT * { <MY_IND_URI> a ?cls }` - clearly this will only give you direct classes, the hierarchy is up to you, property paths would be the way to go.

Comment: Let us know if something is missing to solve your task, e.g. if you need the full class hierarchy or just the directly asserted classes. Once you're done, feel free to post your own answer and mark the question as being solved.

Comment: Thank you for your response. the command gives the class that individual belong to, but in case I need to show the whole hierarchy of that individual

Comment: then you can use SPARQL property paths, to get the inferred classes as well. `SELECT * { <MY_IND_URI> rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* ?cls }` But it won't return a tree if you're asking for that